# Camel Spring Boot Actuator Not Working In Container

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using [this](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot) Camel example as a reference and changed the Initializer to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` so that I can deploy to JBoss EAP 6.4.

**When running this as a SpringBoot application:**

- The Spring Actuator endpoints like `/info` work. `/health` even returns the health of the Camel Context, however Camel Actuator endpoints like `/routes` return http 404.

**When deploying to JBoss:**

- None of the actuator endpoints work. They all return http 404.

The problem is not unique to the demo, all of our Containerized Camel Spring Boot Applications running in JBoss have this same problem, and to be clear, these applications are entirely functional otherwise.

---

*bootstrap.yml*

```
camel:
   springboot:
     name: Demo
  health:
    check:
      routes:
        enabled: true
      indicator:
        enabled: true
endpoints:
  actuator:
    enabled: true
  health:
    enabled: true
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

---

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: are you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan not yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use below in *Application.yml* file.

```
camel:
  springboot:
    health.indicator.enabled:true
management:
  security:
    enabled:false
```

Comment: I have the same problem of accessing spring specific endpoints like normal @RestController which has no relation with Camel. For any such request it forwards to CamelServlet which does not recognize spring specific endpoints. Any idea on this?